# Custom UITabBar Background image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I Have this Image for my `UITabBar`:
[image]

And this is how i add it to the Tab:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewTabBar.png"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selection.png"]];
```

And i noticed that when i rotate the device to landscape mode the image won't re-size to all the screen.
How i can re-size it?

Comment: How tall is your png background? I mean, its height. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to incorporate [`resizableimageWithCapInsets:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:), like this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selection.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)]];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin || UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Or experiment with it;